# Slack API: Attach File Block in Modal

Tags: slack-api, slack-block-kit, slack-bot

I am trying to develop a Slack app to open Tickets on a Kanban Board on Notion from Slack directly.
All good, except in the case the user wants to open a ticket with a file attached.

I haven't seen any action available for attaching files to include in my Modal.

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

according to this discussion, there is no option available except for user to send file to a bot through a direct message:

https://forums.slackcommunity.com/s/question/0D53a000097mYhrCAE/can-we-upload-document-in-modals

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).